# Formatting string into appropriate UTC offset

Tags: php, regex, utc

I have strings like:

```
-4:00
3:15
+8:30
```

I need to format them as UTC offset values like:

```
-0400
+0315
+0815
```

How can I convert the sample strings to the final strings? I know it probably uses some combo of `str_replace` and `sprintf`, but I cannot work it out.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're still looking for a simple solution: `$offset = vsprintf('%+03d:%02d', sscanf($offset, '%d:%d'));` - [full answer and demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072350/formatting-string-into-appropriate-utc-offset/7072627#7072627).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three steps here it is:

```
$offset = preg_replace('/:/','',$offset);
$offset = preg_replace('/\b(?=\d{3}$)/', '0', $offset);
$offset = preg_replace('/^(?=\d)/m', '+', $offset);
```

You can remove the `m` flag on the second regex if you are only passing one offset at a time.

Comment: This is very close. Values like `-10:30` do not lose the `:`. Also, and this was neglected in the original question, some values don't have a `:`. For instance, there are values like `-9`. How can I get those to pick up the leading and trailing 0's? Thanks so far!

Comment: I think I fixed both of those issues, but I didn't test it out. Heading home, but I'll check in later if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a pretty simple re-formatting to me ([Demo](http://codepad.org/PXzpG4YW)):

```
$offset = vsprintf('%+03d%02d', sscanf($offset, '%d:%d'));
```

`0` is treated as positive number (`+` as in `+0000`).

Comment: +1 for simplicity and not using `preg_replace`. Minor nitpick: the colon should be omitted in the output.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Thanks to the format string, the output is easy to change ;) - now corrected, added some more values to the demo as well.

Comment: +1 I like how simple it is. Though it breaks if the offset is already specified correctly. Try out -900.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the input string matches. If it does, remove the whole matching string from the result, and if there are only two parts, the leading sign is missing. In this case, add a plus in the beginning and pad the hour to a length of 2. Finally convert that array into a string.

```
foreach (array('-1:50','1:50','+1:50','-12:00','12:00','+12:00') as $input) {
  echo $input . ': ';

  if (preg_match('/^([-+])?([1-9][0-9]?):([0-9]{2})$/DX', $input, $asMatch) === 1) {
    unset($asMatch[0]);
    if ($asMatch[1] === '') {
      array_unshift($asMatch, '+');
    }
    $asMatch[2] = str_pad($asMatch[2], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo implode('', $asMatch);
  }

  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working. `-12:00` becomes `=-1200`. In fact, all negative values pick up an `=` sign. All positive values retain the `:` and do not have a leading zero.

Comment: @Sardine I updated my answer and added 6 test cases. They all work now.

Comment: Simple depends on the view: If the input already is verified to be valid, your solution is quite nice. If not, well, you'll get a result but it is not the expected one, and the code cannot flag it. It is all about how much you trust (user) input.

Comment: @Shi: There is no problem to check sscanf's return values. Your code doesn't error check btw, it will return an empty string instead of an error as well. Just saying, you're right that error checks should be done.

Answer (score 0):

A set of regex substitutions for the input formats you want to support would probably be the most readable and maintainable.

Comment: I still don't have regex down. You have an idea of what I would do?

Comment: @Henning Makholm: I would first opt for `sscanf` for the input formats. It's sort of regular expression, too, but not that complex.